# Use case sensitive search for lower-case string using smartcase

Tags: vim, search

I normally enable `smartcase` in my `.vimrc`.

**Without `smartcase`:**

- If I want case-insensitive search, I write in upper-case or lower-case (doesn't matter) and append a `\c` at the end of the query.
- Case-sensitive search happens by default.

**With `smartcase`:**

- If I want case insensitive search, I write all in lower-case.
- If I want case sensitive search, I write the upper-case letters in upper-case.

But, with `smartcase` enabled, how can I say that I want a case sensitive search of a lower-case pattern? I was expecting that appending a `\c` would revert the type of search (so that if I had written all in lower-case, i.e. case-insensitive search, it would turn to a case-sensitive search; and if I had written some upper-case letters, i.e. case-sensitive search, it would turn to a case-insensitive search), but that does not seem to be the case (no pun intended).

Comment: Did you know there is a stackexchange sister site for vi/vim?

Comment: `\c` is not a toggle, but actually forces case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `\C` (uppercase) in your search pattern

See [`:help /ignorecase`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cc): *"\C" does the opposite: Force matching case for the whole pattern.*